# Default value for Price field

Tags: commerce

I'd like to know if there's a way to assign a default value in the Price field in Drupal Commerce. Currently, there are no field settings available.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for the default price field, because Drupal locks down the field / widget settings for "locked" fields. This is a general Drupal issue, but you could work around it by using an alternate price field that you add custom to your product type paired with a product pricing rule that swaps that price in at the start of the pricing process. You'd have to do a form alter or something to hide the default price field from your product forms.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I can't unlock it? It seems that it's much more complicated that I expected it to be. I'm curious, do you know why this locking is done in the first place?

Comment: We had to lock it to prevent its deletion since so much of Drupal Commerce depends on that field being there. Unfortunately, Drupal 7 doesn't differentiate between a field that can't be deleted and a field that can't have its settings edited. Hopefully that's resolved in Drupal 8; I filed an issue for it but can't remember where it ended up.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily unlock the field, set the default price and lock it again.  The PHP code is as follows:

```
$field = field_read_field('commerce_price');
$field['locked'] = 0;  // 0: unlock; 1: lock.
field_update_field($field);
```

You could run it using drush eval (use backslash to escape the $ and put it all on one line) or the php block from the devel module.  Credit: http://atlantic-canary.net/en/how-to-lockunlock-a-field-in-drupal.

Don't forget to lock it again after to make the field safe again.

Answer (score 0):

Instill devel module
Enable the devel module either by drush en or from admin/build/modules.
It will generate several blocks and look for the one named ‘Execute PHP’ enable it by setting it to a preferred  region .
Write the code you want to check on the text area for example and then press execute to see the result.

so here we will use this code

`$field_name = 'field_name';
$field = field_read_field($field_name);
$field['locked'] = 0; // 0: unlock; 1: lock.
field_update_field($field);`

note: this line $field_name = 'field_name'; you have to add your filed name for example like this $field_name = commerce_price;

if you got any error such as displayed as messages “Notice: Undefined index” or “Notice: Undefined variable” and your logs will grow insanely…

the solution is to add in your settings.php the line

`ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE');`